# JsonPath Fetch string after filter

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am using Jayway JsonPath 2.2 version in JAVA. I have few questions on the same.

Sample JSON:

`{
  "l5": [
    {
      "type": "type1",
      "result": [
        "res1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "type2",
      "result": [
        "r1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

1. I want to fetch a string after a filter is applied?

   Eg:

   Path used to fetch a string is `l5[?(@.type == 'type2')].type`
   Expected result: `type2` (string), but getting ["type2"] (array)

   Please correct the path if i am doing anything wrong to fetch it as a string?
2. Unable to index the resultant array after the filter is applied. How can i achieve the same?

   Eg:

   If i use the path `l5[?(@.type == 'type2')][0]`, instead of returning me the first `JSONObject` it returns `[]`
3. Is it possible to extract substring from a string using jsonPath?

   Something like `l5[0].type[0,2] => res`

**Note:** I cannot do any operation in JAVA, as i wanted to keep the library generic?

Answer (score 0):

> The return value of jsonPath is always an array, quoted from [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

So, the operation1 you are trying is not possible i.e. String value will never be returned.
Even operation 2 and operation 3 doesn't look feasible with jayway jsonpath.

Good read on [jayway Jsonpath](http://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath).

Only Possible way for operation 1 and 2 looks something like below:-

```
String jsonpath="l5[?(@.type == 'type2')].type";
        DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
        List<String> typeDataList= jsonContext.read(jsonpath);
        System.out.println(typeDataList.get(0)); //type2
```

Comment: Only if we set the configuration to ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST, it returns array. Otherwise it will cast the value according to the return data. Eg: If i give the path `l5[0].type`, i am getting proper string **type1**. But only in case of filters, i am not getting. Also i cannot add extra java code to achieve the same.

Comment: @LakshanPrabhu did you get the solution for this?